# Detect weather a node is a leaf node in NEO4J

Tags: java, neo4j

I have a node "mynode". 
How can i say that it is a leafnode? I want to get a boolean value (true/false). Like

```
if(mynode is a leafnode)
{
......
}
```

I am coding in java.

Comment: The criteria heavily depends on your definition of "leaf". Provide more context to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: By leaf node i mean a node that has no OUTGOING relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java:
node.getRelationships(Direction.OUTGOING) will give you outgoing relationships.
http://api.neo4j.org/1.8.2/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html#getRelationships%28org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction%29

You can also write a Cypher query for that:

```
start n=<look up your node>
match n-[r]->()
return count(r) as outgoing
```

Comment: or even shorter in Java: [Node.hasRelationship(Direction.OUTGOING)](http://api.neo4j.org/1.8.2/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html#hasRelationship(org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction))